# What would happen if 2 different photons overlap each other while travelling in the same direction?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, wavelength, superposition

Imagine 2 photons with same wavelength but from different sources overlap each other and since they don't interact with each other I like to know if there is any changes to their wavelength vs solo? Consider only low energy for simplicity. I was thinking they become brighter but then that can only work if they travel side by side so only conclusion is their momentum adds up and no change in frequency right?

Comment: this might interest you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.  As you stated, the two photons will not interact with each other.  If overlapping changed their frequencies it would constitute interaction-- and so there is no frequency change.  The momentum of the two photons is just the sum of their individual momenta, and the energy of the two is just the sum of their individual energies.

The above is true in a vacuum.  However, in a material medium photons *can* interact in various ways, including changing frequencies, exchanging momenta and energy, and so on.

Comment: Thanks this clears up everything for me.

Comment: In a material, more complicated Feynman diagrams are needed that allow for energy exchanges with the medium. The photons are always massless and travel with velocity c, though light , superposition of photons, can have a much lower one.

Comment: Are you saying that the transit time of a very weak (single photon at a time) beam through a refractive plate would be shorter than the transit time for a brighter beam?  That doesn't seem right.